# selenium RC python, using find_element_by_link_text

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have the following HTML element which I am trying to find through find_element_by_link_text

```
<A href="/help/index.html?sys_optimization_community.html" target="_blank"><IMG src="/images/help.gif" border="0" alt="Help" hspace="3"></A>
```

As you can see there is no link text. Can I used find_element_by_link_text or is there any other API with selenium python library that I can use. Please help.

Comment: Thanks @RocketDonkey for formatting.

Comment: No prob - figured there was something there :)

Comment: If anyone knows using selenium RC with ROBOT open source framework,                                                              Check Help
    Focus  link="/help/index.html?sys_optimization_community.html"
    Press Key Native  10  10
    Title Should Be  blah blah

Comment: I am struggling with formatting :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use find_element_by_link_text. You have 3 options.

1. If you have control over html add an id and get it by id.
2. Get all links in the page and use the one with specified link (href value).
3. Best way: Use xpath.

Comment: How do I get all the links in the page? Also with xpath is this something like \a[@src='/images/help.gif']. When I tried with target=_blank I am getting an error in the robot framework saying something like "unable to find type"

Comment: To get all links use findElement(By.tagName("a")); Iterate it. to get href value use elem.getAttribute("href")

Comment: Xpath worked. I will try the other method as well.. I tried //TD/a[@target=_blank] Thanks.